# How to "dump" request body?

Tags: okhttp

Is there any way to get request in the raw representation? I need something like this:

```
POST /user HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: okhttp/4.9.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a following strange solution in my interceptor:

```
val buffer = okio.Buffer()
request.body?.writeTo(buffer)

    val rawRequest = buildString {
        append("${request.method} ${chain.request().url.encodedPath} ${chain.connection()?.protocol().toString().toUpperCase()}\n")
        append(chain.request().headers.map { "${it.first}: ${it.second}\n" }.reduce { acc, s -> "$acc$s" })
        append(buffer.readString(Charsets.UTF_8))
    }
    
    
    Log.e("RAW request", "$rawRequest")
```

One important thing: You have to use **networkInterceptor**

Answer (score 1):

Try the built in [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) or write your own.

Or try [Chucker](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker) if you're on Android.

Comment: These approaches don't solve my problem at all. For instance: logging interceptor doesn't return all necessary headers. I've already tried these ways.